# How does this magic JavaScript code work?

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, deobfuscation

This is a small piece of JavaScript code that alerts "Hello world":

```
ﾟωﾟﾉ=/｀ｍ´）ﾉ~┻━┻//*´∇｀*/['_'];o=(ﾟｰﾟ)=_=3;c=(ﾟΘﾟ)=(ﾟｰﾟ)-(ﾟｰﾟ);(ﾟДﾟ)=(ﾟΘﾟ)=(o^_^o)/(o^_^o);(ﾟДﾟ)={ﾟΘﾟ:'_',ﾟωﾟﾉ:((ﾟωﾟﾉ==3)+'_')[ﾟΘﾟ],ﾟｰﾟﾉ:(ﾟωﾟﾉ+'_')[o^_^o-(ﾟΘﾟ)],ﾟДﾟﾉ:((ﾟｰﾟ==3)+'_')[ﾟｰﾟ]};(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟΘﾟ]=((ﾟωﾟﾉ==3)+'_')[c^_^o];(ﾟДﾟ)['c']=((ﾟДﾟ)+'_')[(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟｰﾟ)-(ﾟΘﾟ)];(ﾟДﾟ)['o']=((ﾟДﾟ)+'_')[ﾟΘﾟ];(ﾟoﾟ)=(ﾟДﾟ)['c']+(ﾟДﾟ)['o']+(ﾟωﾟﾉ+'_')[ﾟΘﾟ]+((ﾟωﾟﾉ==3)+'_')[ﾟｰﾟ]+((ﾟДﾟ)+'_')[(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟｰﾟ)]+((ﾟｰﾟ==3)+'_')[ﾟΘﾟ]+((ﾟｰﾟ==3)+'_')[(ﾟｰﾟ)-(ﾟΘﾟ)]+(ﾟДﾟ)['c']+((ﾟДﾟ)+'_')[(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟｰﾟ)]+(ﾟДﾟ)['o']+((ﾟｰﾟ==3)+'_')[ﾟΘﾟ];(ﾟДﾟ)['_']=(o^_^o)[ﾟoﾟ][ﾟoﾟ];(ﾟεﾟ)=((ﾟｰﾟ==3)+'_')[ﾟΘﾟ]+(ﾟДﾟ).ﾟДﾟﾉ+((ﾟДﾟ)+'_')[(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟｰﾟ)]+((ﾟｰﾟ==3)+'_')[o^_^o-ﾟΘﾟ]+((ﾟｰﾟ==3)+'_')[ﾟΘﾟ]+(ﾟωﾟﾉ+'_')[ﾟΘﾟ];(ﾟｰﾟ)+=(ﾟΘﾟ);(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]='\\';(ﾟДﾟ).ﾟΘﾟﾉ=(ﾟДﾟ+ﾟｰﾟ)[o^_^o-(ﾟΘﾟ)];(oﾟｰﾟo)=(ﾟωﾟﾉ+'_')[c^_^o];(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟoﾟ]='\"';(ﾟДﾟ)['_']((ﾟДﾟ)['_'](ﾟεﾟ+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟoﾟ]+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ)+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ))+(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+(ﾟｰﾟ)+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ))+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+((o^_^o)+(o^_^o))+((o^_^o)-(ﾟΘﾟ))+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+((o^_^o)+(o^_^o))+(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ))+(c^_^o)+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟｰﾟ)+((o^_^o)-(ﾟΘﾟ))+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ)+(c^_^o)+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+(ﾟｰﾟ)+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ))+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ))+(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ))+(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ))+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(o^_^o))+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟｰﾟ)+(c^_^o)+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+((o^_^o)-(ﾟΘﾟ))+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(o^_^o))+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ))+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(o^_^o))+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+((o^_^o)+(o^_^o))+((o^_^o)-(ﾟΘﾟ))+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ))+(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟｰﾟ)+((o^_^o)-(ﾟΘﾟ))+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ))+(ﾟΘﾟ)+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟoﾟ])(ﾟΘﾟ))('_');
```

A good looking version:

```
ﾟωﾟﾉ = /｀ｍ´）ﾉ~┻━┻//*´∇｀*/['_'];
o = (ﾟｰﾟ) = _ = 3;
c = (ﾟΘﾟ) = (ﾟｰﾟ) - (ﾟｰﾟ);
(ﾟДﾟ) = (ﾟΘﾟ) = (o^_^o)/(o^_^o);
(ﾟДﾟ) = {
  ﾟΘﾟ:  '_',
  ﾟωﾟﾉ: ((ﾟωﾟﾉ==3)+'_')[ﾟΘﾟ],
  ﾟｰﾟﾉ: (ﾟωﾟﾉ+'_')[o^_^o-(ﾟΘﾟ)],
  ﾟДﾟﾉ: ((ﾟｰﾟ==3)+'_')[ﾟｰﾟ]
};
(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟΘﾟ] = ((ﾟωﾟﾉ==3)+'_')[c^_^o];
(ﾟДﾟ)['c'] = ((ﾟДﾟ)+'_')[(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟｰﾟ)-(ﾟΘﾟ)];
(ﾟДﾟ)['o'] = ((ﾟДﾟ)+'_')[ﾟΘﾟ];
(ﾟoﾟ)=(ﾟДﾟ)['c'] + (ﾟДﾟ)['o'] + (ﾟωﾟﾉ + '_')[ﾟΘﾟ] + ((ﾟωﾟﾉ==3) + '_')[ﾟｰﾟ] + ((ﾟДﾟ) + '_')[(ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟｰﾟ)] + ((ﾟｰﾟ==3) + '_')[ﾟΘﾟ] + ((ﾟｰﾟ==3) + '_')[(ﾟｰﾟ) - (ﾟΘﾟ)] + (ﾟДﾟ)['c'] + ((ﾟДﾟ) + '_')[(ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟｰﾟ)] + (ﾟДﾟ)['o'] + ((ﾟｰﾟ==3) + '_')[ﾟΘﾟ];
(ﾟДﾟ)['_'] = (o^_^o)[ﾟoﾟ][ﾟoﾟ];
(ﾟεﾟ) = ((ﾟｰﾟ==3) + '_')[ﾟΘﾟ] + (ﾟДﾟ).ﾟДﾟﾉ + ((ﾟДﾟ) + '_')[(ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟｰﾟ)] + ((ﾟｰﾟ==3) + '_')[o^_^o-ﾟΘﾟ] + ((ﾟｰﾟ==3) + '_')[ﾟΘﾟ] + (ﾟωﾟﾉ+'_')[ﾟΘﾟ];
(ﾟｰﾟ) += (ﾟΘﾟ);
(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ] = '\\';
(ﾟДﾟ).ﾟΘﾟﾉ = (ﾟДﾟ+ﾟｰﾟ)[o^_^o-(ﾟΘﾟ)];
(oﾟｰﾟo) = (ﾟωﾟﾉ+'_')[c^_^o];
(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟoﾟ] = '\"';
(ﾟДﾟ)['_']((ﾟДﾟ)['_'](ﾟεﾟ+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟoﾟ]+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ)+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ))+(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+(ﾟｰﾟ)+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ))+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+((o^_^o)+(o^_^o))+((o^_^o)-(ﾟΘﾟ))+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+((o^_^o)+(o^_^o))+(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ))+(c^_^o)+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟｰﾟ)+((o^_^o)-(ﾟΘﾟ))+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ)+(c^_^o)+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+(ﾟｰﾟ)+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ))+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ))+(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ))+(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ))+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(o^_^o))+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟｰﾟ)+(c^_^o)+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+((o^_^o)-(ﾟΘﾟ))+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(o^_^o))+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ))+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(o^_^o))+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+((o^_^o)+(o^_^o))+((o^_^o)-(ﾟΘﾟ))+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ))+(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟｰﾟ)+((o^_^o)-(ﾟΘﾟ))+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+((ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟΘﾟ))+(ﾟΘﾟ)+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟoﾟ])(ﾟΘﾟ))('_');
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E4b5d/1/)

It is taken from here: *https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/23975/obfuscation-challenge/24041#24041*

How does it work? I don't even see the `alert` in that code.

Comment: There is a brief explanation in the third comment to http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/307/obfuscated-hello-world/3946#3946

Comment: @NPE yes, I read that, but the author just give a small hint. I still have no idea how it works...

Comment: The answer you've linked to provides a further link to the original source of the answer. In the comments that follow, an explanation is given - it's using RegEx amongst other tools. _On a side note:_ your 'good looking version' is incorrect - I spotted `='\"';` in the last line, there may be other errors.

Comment: Some hints: in JavaScript you can use almost every Unicode character as variable names. The second thing is that first variable seems to be a regular expression which does some replacements, but I don't get the whole code

Comment: **I found the tool for that** http://utf-8.jp/public/aaencode.html

Comment: See also this [great article by Mathias Bynens](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers) on the topic of JavaScript identifiers.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Before looking closer at the code, you have to know that since JavaScript 1.5 [identifiers](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6) are allowed to contain not just ASCII characters but also Unicode characters.

In this case many of these funny sequences are just identifiers. After exchanging these identifiers by simpler identifiers and removing unnecessary comments and parenthesis, the code looks as follows:

```
a = /｀ｍ´）ﾉ~┻━┻/['_'];
o = b = _ = 3;
c = d = b-b;
e = d = o^_^o/o^_^o;
e = {
  d: '_',
  a: ((a==3)+'_')[d],
  h: (a+'_')[o^_^o-d],
  i: ((b==3)+'_')[b]
};
e[d]   = ((a==3)+'_')[c^_^o];
e['c'] = (e+'_')[b+b-d];
e['o'] = (e+'_')[d];
f      = e['c']+e['o']+(a+'_')[d]+((a==3)+'_')[b]+(e+'_')[b+b]+((b==3)+'_')[d]+((b==3)+'_')[b-d]+e['c']+(e+'_')[b+b]+e['o']+((b==3)+'_')[d];
e['_'] = (o^_^o)[f][f];
g      = ((b==3)+'_')[d]+e.i+(e+'_')[b+b]+((b==3)+'_')[o^_^o-d]+((b==3)+'_')[d]+(a+'_')[d];
b      += d;
e[g]   = '\\';
e.j    = (e+b)[o^_^o-d];
obo    = (a+'_')[c^_^o];
e[f]   = '\"';
e['_'](e['_'](g+e[f]+e[g]+d+b+d+e[g]+d+(b+d)+b+e[g]+d+b+(b+d)+e[g]+d+((o^_^o)+(o^_^o))+((o^_^o)-d)+e[g]+d+((o^_^o)+(o^_^o))+b+e[g]+(b+d)+(c^_^o)+e[g]+b+((o^_^o)-d)+e[g]+d+d+(c^_^o)+e[g]+d+b+(b+d)+e[g]+d+(b+d)+b+e[g]+d+(b+d)+b+e[g]+d+(b+d)+(b+(o^_^o))+e[g]+b+(c^_^o)+e[g]+d+((o^_^o)-d)+(b+(o^_^o))+e[g]+d+(b+d)+(b+(o^_^o))+e[g]+d+((o^_^o)+(o^_^o))+((o^_^o)-d)+e[g]+d+(b+d)+b+e[g]+d+b+b+e[g]+b+((o^_^o)-d)+e[g]+(b+d)+d+e[f])(d))('_');
```

Now we’re able to evaluate each statement at a time:

- `a = /｀ｍ´）ﾉ~┻━┻/['_']` evaluates to `a = undefined`
- `o = b = _ = 3` assigns `o`, `b`, and `_` the integer `3`
- `c = d = b-b` assigns `c` and `d` the integer `0`
- `e = d = o^_^o/o^_^o` assigns `e` and `d` the integer `1` (`o^_^o` evaluates to 3 XOR 3 XOR 3, which yields 3)
- `e = { d: '_', a: ((a==3)+'_')[d], h: (a+'_')[o^_^o-d], i: ((b==3)+'_')[b] }` assigns `e` the object `{ d: '_', a: 'a', h: 'd', i: 'e' }`
- `e[d]   = ((a==3)+'_')[c^_^o]` assigns `e[1]` the string `'f'`
- `e['c'] = (e+'_')[b+b-d]` assigns `e['c']` the string `'c'`
- `e['o'] = (e+'_')[d]` assigns `e['o']` the string `'o'`

This was all just the setup and the following variables are set:

```
a = undefined
b = 3
c = 0
d = 1
e = {
    1: "f",
    a: "a",
    c: "c",
    d: "_",
    h: "d",
    i: "e",
    o: "o"
}
```

The next statement is the first that constructs something:

```
f = e['c'] +             // => "c"
    e['o'] +             // => "o"
    (a+'_')[d] +         // => "undefined_"[1] = "n"
    ((a==3)+'_')[b] +    // => "false_"[3]     = "s"
    (e+'_')[b+b] +       // => "object_"[6]    = "t"
    ((b==3)+'_')[d] +    // => "true_"[1]      = "r"
    ((b==3)+'_')[b-d] +  // => "true_"[2]      = "s"
    e['c'] +             // => "c"
    (e+'_')[b+b] +       // => "object_"[6]    = "t"
    e['o'] +             // => "o"
    ((b==3)+'_')[d];     // => "true"[1]       = "r"
```

So `f = "constructor"`. In the next statement this `"constructor"` is used to retrieve a function:

```
e['_'] = (o^_^o)[f][f]
```

This is equivalent to `(3).constructor.constructor`, which yields the [function `Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function), so:

```
e['_'] = Function
```

This `Function` function is special as one can construct functions dynamically by passing it the function body code via parameter:

```
f = Function("alert(1)")
// equivalent to
f = function() { alert(1) }
```

I’ll skip the next few statements and just write the resulting variables and values:

```
a = undefined
b = 4
c = 0
d = 1
e = {
    1: "f",
    _: Function,
    a: "a",
    c: "c",
    constructor: "\"",
    d: "_",
    h: "d",
    i: "e",
    j: "b",
    o: "o",
    return: "\\"
}
f = "constructor"
obo = "u"
```

The last statement does the final work:

```
e['_'](e['_'](g+e[f]+e[g]+d+b+d+e[g]+d+(b+d)+b+e[g]+d+b+(b+d)+e[g]+d+((o^_^o)+(o^_^o))+((o^_^o)-d)+e[g]+d+((o^_^o)+(o^_^o))+b+e[g]+(b+d)+(c^_^o)+e[g]+b+((o^_^o)-d)+e[g]+d+d+(c^_^o)+e[g]+d+b+(b+d)+e[g]+d+(b+d)+b+e[g]+d+(b+d)+b+e[g]+d+(b+d)+(b+(o^_^o))+e[g]+b+(c^_^o)+e[g]+d+((o^_^o)-d)+(b+(o^_^o))+e[g]+d+(b+d)+(b+(o^_^o))+e[g]+d+((o^_^o)+(o^_^o))+((o^_^o)-d)+e[g]+d+(b+d)+b+e[g]+d+b+b+e[g]+b+((o^_^o)-d)+e[g]+(b+d)+d+e[f])(d))('_');
```

This is equivalent to:

```
Function(Function( … )(1))('_')
```

The long expression builds the following string:

```
return"\141\154\145\162\164\50\42\110\145\154\154\157\40\127\157\162\154\144\42\51"
```

The escaped string evaluates:

```
alert("Hello World")
```

This `return` code is passed to `Function`, which creates an anonymous function like:

```
function anonymous() {
    return"\141\154\145\162\164\50\42\110\145\154\154\157\40\127\157\162\154\144\42\51";
}
```

Which, we know, is equivalent to:

```
function anonymous() {
    return"alert(\"Hello World\")";
}
```

This function is then executed with `1` as parameter, which returns the resulting string:

```
alert("Hello World")
```

This is then passed to `Function` again, which creates a new anonymous function:

```
function anonymous() {
    alert("Hello World");
}
```

Finally, this function is also invoked with `'_'` as parameter.

Comment: Thank you, waiting for this answer. Guy who wrote this stuff is just brilliant, I learned a lot from this answer and [his blog here](http://utf-8.jp/).

Comment: "JavaScript 1.5" isn't really a thing. If you want to quote a specification you should check out the ES3 or ES5 spec. Awesome answer btw.

Answer (score 16):

There is a lot of stuff in here. Parentheses around variables are non-functional.

Basically he constructs this string:

```
return"\141\154\145\162\164\50\42\110\145\154\154\157\40\127\157\162\154\144\42\51"
```

Which is an escaped version of

```
return "alert(\"Hello World\")"
```

And finally does this:

```
Function(Function('return "alert(\\"Hello World\\")"')())()
```

The double `Function` seems like an arbitrary thing to do, but it's not. `Function()` interprets backslashes in the string as escape characters. So the first call decodes, and the second executes.

```
Function("return '\\110\\145\\154\\154\\157'")()
// => "Hello"
```

This is the same code, better formatted, and with "normal" variable names;

```
var1=/｀ｍ´）ﾉ~┻━┻//*´∇｀*/['_'];
three=(threeThenFour)=_=3;
c=(one)=(threeThenFour)-(threeThenFour);
(anObject)=(one)=(three)/(three);
(anObject)={
  one:'_',
  var1:((var1==3)+'_')[one],
  var2ﾉ:(var1+'_')[three-(one)],
  var4ﾉ:((threeThenFour==3)+'_')[threeThenFour]
};
(anObject)[one]=((var1==3)+'_')[c ^ _ ^ three];
(anObject)['c']=((anObject)+'_')[(threeThenFour)+(threeThenFour)-(one)];
(anObject)['three']=((anObject)+'_')[one];
(theConstructor)=(anObject)['c']+
  (anObject)['three']+
  (var1+'_')[one]+
  ((var1==3)+'_')[threeThenFour]+
  ((anObject)+'_')[(threeThenFour)+(threeThenFour)]+
  ((threeThenFour==3)+'_')[one]+
  ((threeThenFour==3)+'_')[(threeThenFour)-(one)]+
  (anObject)['c']+
  ((anObject)+'_')[(threeThenFour)+(threeThenFour)]+
  (anObject)['three']+
  ((threeThenFour==3)+'_')[one];

// theConstructor => "constructor" 

(anObject)['_']=(three)[theConstructor][theConstructor];
(theReturn)=((threeThenFour==3)+'_')[one]+
  (anObject).var4ﾉ+
  ((anObject)+'_')[(threeThenFour)+(threeThenFour)]+
  ((threeThenFour==3)+'_')[three-one]+
  ((threeThenFour==3)+'_')[one]+
  (var1+'_')[one];

// theReturn => "return"

(threeThenFour)+=(one);
(anObject)[theReturn]='\\';
(anObject).var3ﾉ=(anObject+threeThenFour)[three-(one)];
(ovar2o)=(var1+'_')[c ^ _ ^ three];
(anObject)[theConstructor]='\"';

// (anObject)['_'] => Function

(anObject)['_'](
  (anObject)['_'](theReturn+
                 (anObject)[theConstructor]+
                 (anObject)[theReturn]+
                 (one)+
                 (threeThenFour)+
                 (one)+
                 (anObject)[theReturn]+
                 (one)+
                 ((threeThenFour)+(one))+
                 (threeThenFour)+
                 (anObject)[theReturn]+
                 (one)+(
                   threeThenFour)+
                 ((threeThenFour)+(one))+
                 (anObject)[theReturn]+
                 (one)+
                 ((three)+(three))+
                 ((three)-(one))+
                 (anObject)[theReturn]+
                 (one)+
                 ((three)+(three))+
                 (threeThenFour)+
                 (anObject)[theReturn]+
                 ((threeThenFour)+(one))+
                 (c ^ _ ^ three)+
                 (anObject)[theReturn]+
                 (threeThenFour)+((three)-(one))+
                 (anObject)[theReturn]+
                 (one)+(one)+
                 (c ^ _ ^ three)+
                 (anObject)[theReturn]+
                 (one)+
                 (threeThenFour)+
                 ((threeThenFour)+(one))+
                 (anObject)[theReturn]+
                 (one)+
                 ((threeThenFour)+(one))+
                 (threeThenFour)+
                 (anObject)[theReturn]+
                 (one)+
                 ((threeThenFour)+(one))+
                 (threeThenFour)+
                 (anObject)[theReturn]+
                 (one)+
                 ((threeThenFour)+(one))+
                 ((threeThenFour)+(three))+
                 (anObject)[theReturn]+
                 (threeThenFour)+
                 (c ^ _ ^ three)+
                 (anObject)[theReturn]+
                 (one)+
                 ((three)-(one))+
                 ((threeThenFour)+(three))+
                 (anObject)[theReturn]+
                 (one)+
                 ((threeThenFour)+(one))+
                 ((threeThenFour)+(three))+
                 (anObject)[theReturn]+
                 (one)+
                 ((three)+(three))+
                 ((three)-(one))+
                 (anObject)[theReturn]+
                 (one)+
                 ((threeThenFour)+(one))+
                 (threeThenFour)+
                 (anObject)[theReturn]+
                 (one)+
                 (threeThenFour)+
                 (threeThenFour)+
                 (anObject)[theReturn]+
                 (threeThenFour)+
                 ((three)-(one))+
                 (anObject)[theReturn]+
                 ((threeThenFour)+(one))+
                 (one)+
                 (anObject)[theConstructor]
                )
  (one)
)('_');
```

Comment: How does `ﾟωﾟﾉ` become `var` ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir it doesn't. I've arbitary renamed it to `var1`. It's working JavaScript, and not "best practice" JavaScript. You won't find any `var`s in here.

Comment: Is there an online tool which does it ? (not just encoding, I mean this ^ one )

Comment: @RoyiNamir Deobfuscation? IDK, I did it with search and replace, regularly checking that it still works.

Comment: No - I meant obfuscation. I know regular tools but which do not yield this kind of obfuscation.

Comment: @RoyiNamir I don't know that either.

Answer (score 10):

Let me explain the key steps:

The code creates an object named Д and then adds a property `'_'` that has a value of magic JavaScript [Function constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function). In JavaScript, you can execute any string as code by passing it to Function constructor.

How does `(ﾟДﾟ)['_']` contain Function constructor? It's clever technique done by following line:

```
(ﾟДﾟ)['_'] = (o^_^o)[ﾟoﾟ][ﾟoﾟ];
```

Here o and _ is set to 3. So `o^_^o` returns to 3. Obviously author could have just used o because `o^_^o` returns the same value but I guess he has good taste for obfuscation :). So the above expression now becomes `(3)[ﾟoﾟ][ﾟoﾟ]`.

The value of `ﾟoﾟ` in square bracket is set to the string "constructor" that was built by concatenation in previous statement. It uses a very clever way to build the string  "constructor" by plucking away individual characters from built-in JavaScript strings like "object", "true", "false" and "undefined" which are generated from JavaScript expressions converted to string. Apparently author couldn't find character "c" to pluck away from these built-in strings so he had to write that one explicitly. Note that the character in square bracket is ﾟoﾟ which is Unicode character, not the simple o used in round brackets although both looks very similar. When you do `(3)("constructor")` it returns the [Number constructor function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number). The constructor of Number constructor is the Function constructor. So by doing `(3)("constructor")("constructor")` you get Function constructor which now you can finally pass an arbitrary string to execute it.

The last line builds the string `"alert(\"Hello World\")"` and passes it to the Function constructor to execute.

Question is how do we get that string `"alert(\"Hello World\")"` without typing actual alphabet? The clever technique is to use `\xxx` where xxx is octal number and translates to a character. To get this string the numbers you need are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 and 8. But you actually don't need all of these, instead you can produce them by simple arithmetic with three numbers 0, 1 and 4. So for example, to produce the character `'a'` in "alert", you need ASCII decimal 97 or octal 141, i.e., `\141`. If you have only 0, 1 and 4 stored in some property of above object, you can concatenate them to produce `'a'`. This way you can generate any string even if all that you have is 0, 1 and 4 stored in some properties of Д object. Clever? You bet!