# JavaScript - Why does this code alert a message?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, v8, ecmascript-2016

I don't know much about JavaScript, but I found this code as a part of some game engine code. I tried to inspect it, because I noticed this part of code alerts a message and I really cannot figure out how. Here is the minimal code (I reduced it and extracted from original script and I changed variable names to single letters):

```js
var a = '͏‪͏‪‪‪‪‪͏͏‪‪‪‪͏‪͏͏‪͏͏‪‪‪͏‪͏‪‪͏‪‪͏‪‪‪‪‪‪͏͏‪͏‪‪͏‪‪͏͏‪͏‪͏͏͏͏‪‪‪͏͏͏͏͏‪‪͏‪‪͏‪͏‪‪‪͏͏͏‪͏‪‪‪͏‪‪‪͏‪‪‪͏‪͏͏͏‪‪‪‪͏‪‪͏‪‪͏‪‪‪͏͏‪‪‪‪͏‪‪͏‪‪‪‪‪͏͏͏‪‪‪‪‪͏‪͏‪‪‪‪‪͏͏͏‪‪‪‪͏‪‪͏‪‪‪͏‪͏͏͏‪‪‪‪‪͏‪͏‪‪‪‪͏͏‪͏‪‪‪͏͏͏͏͏‪‪‪‪‪͏͏͏‪‪‪‪‪͏‪͏‪‪͏‪‪͏‪͏‪‪‪͏͏͏‪͏‪‪‪͏‪‪‪͏‪‪‪‪‪͏͏͏‪‪‪‪͏‪‪͏‪͏‪‪‪͏‪͏‪͏‪‪‪͏‪͏͏‪͏‪͏͏͏͏͏‪͏‪͏͏͏͏‪‪‪͏‪͏‪͏‪‪‪͏͏͏‪͏‪‪͏‪‪‪͏͏‪‪‪͏͏‪͏͏‪‪‪‪‪͏͏͏‪‪‪‪‪͏‪͏‪‪‪‪͏͏‪͏‪‪‪͏‪‪͏͏‪‪‪‪͏‪͏͏‪‪‪͏‪‪‪͏‪͏‪‪‪͏‪͏͏‪͏‪͏‪‪͏‪‪‪͏͏͏‪͏‪‪‪͏͏‪‪͏‪‪‪͏͏‪‪͏‪‪‪‪͏‪‪͏‪‪‪͏͏‪‪͏‪‪‪‪͏‪‪͏‪‪‪‪͏‪‪͏‪‪‪͏͏‪‪͏‪‪‪‪͏‪‪͏‪‪‪‪͏‪‪͏‪‪‪‪͏‪‪͏‪‪͏‪‪͏‪͏‪‪‪‪͏‪͏͏‪‪‪͏‪‪‪͏‪͏‪‪‪͏‪͏͏‪͏‪͏͏‪͏͏‪͏‪͏͏͏͏͏‪͏‪͏͏‪͏‪‪‪‪‪‪͏͏‪͏‪‪‪͏‪͏‪͏‪‪͏‪‪͏͏‪͏‪͏͏͏͏‪‪‪͏‪͏‪͏‪͏‪‪͏‪‪͏‪‪‪‪‪͏‪͏‪‪‪‪͏͏‪͏‪͏‪‪͏‪‪͏‪‪‪‪͏͏͏͏‪͏‪‪‪͏‪͏‪‪‪‪‪͏‪͏‪͏‪‪͏‪‪͏‪‪͏‪‪‪‪͏‪͏‪‪‪͏‪͏͏‪͏‪͏͏‪͏‪‪‪͏͏͏‪͏‪‪‪͏‪‪‪͏‪‪͏‪‪‪͏͏‪‪‪‪‪͏͏͏‪‪‪‪‪͏‪͏‪‪‪͏͏‪͏͏‪͏‪‪‪͏‪͏‪͏‪‪‪͏‪͏‪‪‪‪‪͏‪͏͏‪͏‪͏‪‪͏‪‪͏‪‪‪‪͏‪‪‪‪‪͏͏͏‪‪‪‪͏͏‪͏͏‪͏͏͏͏‪͏‪‪‪͏‪͏‪͏‪‪‪͏͏͏‪͏͏‪͏‪͏‪‪͏͏‪͏͏͏͏‪͏‪‪‪‪‪͏‪͏‪‪‪‪͏‪͏͏‪͏‪‪͏‪‪͏͏‪͏͏͏͏‪͏‪‪‪‪‪͏‪͏‪‪‪‪͏‪‪͏‪‪‪‪͏͏‪͏‪͏‪‪‪͏‪͏͏‪͏‪͏‪‪͏͏‪͏‪͏͏͏͏‪‪‪‪͏͏͏͏͏‪͏͏͏͏‪͏‪‪͏‪‪‪‪͏‪‪‪͏‪‪‪͏͏‪͏‪͏‪‪͏‪͏‪‪͏‪‪͏‪‪‪‪‪͏‪͏‪͏‪‪‪͏‪͏‪‪‪͏‪‪͏͏‪‪‪‪͏͏͏͏͏‪͏‪͏‪‪͏‪͏‪‪͏‪‪͏‪‪‪‪‪‪͏͏͏‪͏‪͏͏‪͏‪‪‪͏‪͏‪͏‪‪‪‪͏͏͏͏‪‪‪‪‪͏‪͏͏‪͏‪͏͏‪͏‪‪‪͏‪͏͏͏‪‪‪‪͏͏‪͏‪‪͏‪‪‪‪͏‪͏‪‪͏‪‪͏‪‪͏‪‪‪‪͏‪͏‪‪‪͏‪͏‪‪‪‪‪͏‪͏͏‪͏‪͏͏‪͏‪͏‪‪͏‪‪͏‪‪‪͏͏‪‪͏‪͏‪‪‪͏‪͏͏‪͏‪͏‪‪͏‪‪‪‪͏‪͏͏‪‪‪͏͏‪͏͏‪‪‪‪‪͏͏͏͏‪͏͏͏͏‪͏‪‪‪‪‪͏‪͏‪‪‪‪͏‪‪͏‪‪‪‪͏‪‪͏‪‪‪‪‪͏͏͏‪‪‪‪͏‪‪͏‪‪‪͏͏͏‪͏‪͏‪‪͏‪‪͏‪‪‪‪͏‪‪͏‪‪‪͏͏͏͏͏‪͏‪‪͏‪‪͏‪‪‪‪‪‪͏͏‪‪‪‪‪͏‪͏͏‪͏‪͏͏‪͏‪‪‪‪͏‪͏͏‪‪‪‪͏‪‪͏‪‪͏‪‪‪‪͏‪͏‪‪͏‪‪͏‪͏‪‪‪͏‪͏‪‪͏‪‪‪͏͏‪‪‪‪͏͏‪͏‪‪‪͏‪͏‪͏‪‪‪‪͏‪͏͏‪‪͏‪‪͏‪͏‪‪‪‪͏͏‪͏͏‪͏͏͏͏‪͏‪‪‪͏‪‪͏͏͏‪͏͏‪‪‪͏͏‪‪‪͏‪‪͏‪‪͏͏‪‪͏͏‪‪͏‪‪‪‪͏‪‪‪͏͏‪͏͏͏‪͏‪͏͏͏͏‪‪͏‪͏͏‪͏͏‪͏͏͏͏͏͏‪‪͏‪‪‪‪͏‪‪͏͏‪‪͏͏͏‪͏͏‪‪‪͏‪‪͏‪‪͏‪͏‪‪͏‪‪‪͏͏‪‪͏‪‪‪‪͏‪‪‪͏͏͏͏͏‪‪‪͏͏͏‪͏‪‪‪͏͏‪͏͏‪‪‪͏͏‪‪͏‪‪‪͏‪͏͏͏‪‪‪͏‪͏‪͏‪‪‪͏‪‪͏͏‪‪‪͏‪‪‪͏‪‪‪‪͏͏͏͏‪‪‪‪͏͏‪͏‪‪‪‪͏‪͏͏‪‪‪‪͏‪‪͏‪‪‪‪‪͏͏͏‪‪‪‪‪͏‪͏‪‪‪‪‪‪͏͏͏‪͏͏‪‪‪͏͏‪͏‪͏͏‪͏‪‪‪͏‪‪‪͏‪‪͏‪͏͏‪͏‪‪‪͏‪͏͏͏‪‪͏‪͏͏͏͏͏‪͏‪͏͏͏͏‪͏‪‪‪‪‪͏͏‪͏‪‪‪͏͏‪‪‪͏͏‪‪͏‪‪‪͏͏͏͏͏‪‪͏‪‪͏͏͏‪‪͏‪͏͏‪͏‪‪‪͏‪͏͏͏͏‪͏‪͏͏͏͏‪‪͏‪͏͏‪͏͏‪͏‪͏͏‪͏͏‪͏‪͏͏‪͏‪͏‪‪‪‪‪͏͏‪‪‪‪͏‪͏‪‪͏‪͏‪͏͏‪‪͏‪‪‪‪͏‪‪͏‪͏͏‪͏‪‪͏‪‪‪͏͏͏‪͏‪͏͏͏͏‪‪‪͏͏͏͏͏‪‪͏‪‪‪‪͏‪‪‪͏͏͏͏͏͏‪͏‪͏͏͏͏͏‪͏‪͏͏‪͏͏‪͏‪͏͏‪͏͏‪‪‪͏‪‪͏‪‪͏͏‪͏‪͏‪‪‪͏‪‪͏͏‪‪͏͏͏͏‪͏‪‪͏‪‪͏͏͏͏‪͏‪͏͏͏͏‪͏‪‪‪‪‪͏͏‪͏‪͏͏‪';
var b = a.match(/.{8}/g);
var c = b.map(a => [...a].map(a => a == '‪' | 0));
var d = c.map(a => parseInt(a.join``, 2).toString(16));
var e = d.map(a => eval(`'\\x${a.padStart(2, 0)}'`));
var f = eval(e.join``);
```

I'm trying to understand how they succeed to alert a message. It alerts number `12345`, but how? I see some `eval`s here, so I suppose they are making code on the fly, but still I tried using `debugger` but I couldn't find explanation. They are somehow generating code and executing it, I'm still unable to see how.

I tried this code in jsFiddle and it still works and I tried in Node.js and it throw error `alert` is not defined, so I am pretty sure everything this code does is to alert a message.

What trick did they use here? How are they making and evaling code and how do they succeed to alert a message? Is this some sort of encription or what?

My question has absolutely nothing to do with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22588223/how-does-this-magic-javascript-work) question.

Comment: Use a debugger and step through it. Whatever is `eval`'d on the last line obviously contains an `alert`.

Comment: @meagar. No it doesn't contain alert - that is the problem.

Comment: @9098conadygawu you don't know they downvoted you, there are many others that use the site anyone of them could be the one that downvoted.

Comment: @PatrickEvans. When you downvote a post it says "please leave a comment", so I am assuming each downvote should correspond to at least one comment. But you are right, I cannot really tell anything for sure.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels. When I said to him "would you reconsider your vote", I didn't only mean "retract your downvote", I also mean "give a +1 if the question is good"..*"Please delete your comment"* - Ok, i deleted it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels. No, I am not asking for votes, because as I explained on meta, I will delete this account soon, but I am asking for explanation why he didnt leave upvote

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does this magic Javascript work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22588223/how-does-this-magic-javascript-work)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov. No, it is just similar, but really has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: If you don't understand how your code works, how can you categorically state that your code and question have nothing to do with the other?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels. Very simple: because the linked question has so many upvotes. If it had anything with my question, I would receive probably approximately same amount of votes.

Answer (score 1):

The code is all there, hidden in the variable `a`. No, it's not an empty string, its a string consisting of 1888 invisible characters - either `\u034f` or `\u202a` to be precise. So this is in fact just a disguised binary encoding.

The code part

```
var b = a.match(/.{8}/g);
var c = b.map(a => [...a].map(a => a == '‪' | 0));
var d = c.map(a => parseInt(a.join``, 2).toString(16));
```

breaks them in chunks of 8, then converts each chunk from an array of characters to an array of booleans (or rather, the integers `0` and `1`) - notice that it compares the character against the invisible `\u202a`, and then converts each array-of-8-booleans (oh look, an octet!) into an actual byte and gets a hex representation of it. Here's the hex string (`d.join('')`):

```
5f3d275b7e5b28706d7177747b6e7b7c7d7c7b747d79707c7d6d71777c7b5d5d282875716e727c7d79767a775d2b7173737b737b7b737b7b7b6d7a775d2928297e5d5b28755b7d795b785d7d5b6f5d2971776e7c7d725d5d7d2b6f7c792175712b217d7a5b217d7b795d2b2878216f772b5b7d5d76782b5b7e2975787d2974796f5b6f5d7d295b735d2b7a727c217d7b7b7c7b715b7b705b7e7d297a7b6f5b5d6e79757a6d792176273b666f722869206f66276d6e6f707172737475767778797a7b7c7d7e272977697468285f2e73706c6974286929295f3d6a6f696e28706f702829293b6576616c285f29
```

The part

```
d.map(a => eval(`'\\x${a.padStart(2, 0)}'`));
```

has each of them parsed into a character, using a backslash escape. `String.fromCharCode` would have been the simpler choice. Also the `padStart` is not even required here, given that none of the bytes is a control character with a byte value less than 16. Maybe this would've been more familiar:

```
"\x5f\x3d\x27\x5b\x7e\x5b\x28\x70\x6d\x71\x77\x74\x7b\x6e\x7b\x7c\x7d\x7c\x7b\x74\x7d\x79\x70\x7c\x7d\x6d\x71\x77\x7c\x7b\x5d\x5d\x28\x28\x75\x71\x6e\x72\x7c\x7d\x79\x76\x7a\x77\x5d\x2b\x71\x73\x73\x7b\x73\x7b\x7b\x73\x7b\x7b\x7b\x6d\x7a\x77\x5d\x29\x28\x29\x7e\x5d\x5b\x28\x75\x5b\x7d\x79\x5b\x78\x5d\x7d\x5b\x6f\x5d\x29\x71\x77\x6e\x7c\x7d\x72\x5d\x5d\x7d\x2b\x6f\x7c\x79\x21\x75\x71\x2b\x21\x7d\x7a\x5b\x21\x7d\x7b\x79\x5d\x2b\x28\x78\x21\x6f\x77\x2b\x5b\x7d\x5d\x76\x78\x2b\x5b\x7e\x29\x75\x78\x7d\x29\x74\x79\x6f\x5b\x6f\x5d\x7d\x29\x5b\x73\x5d\x2b\x7a\x72\x7c\x21\x7d\x7b\x7b\x7c\x7b\x71\x5b\x7b\x70\x5b\x7e\x7d\x29\x7a\x7b\x6f\x5b\x5d\x6e\x79\x75\x7a\x6d\x79\x21\x76\x27\x3b\x66\x6f\x72\x28\x69\x20\x6f\x66\x27\x6d\x6e\x6f\x70\x71\x72\x73\x74\x75\x76\x77\x78\x79\x7a\x7b\x7c\x7d\x7e\x27\x29\x77\x69\x74\x68\x28\x5f\x2e\x73\x70\x6c\x69\x74\x28\x69\x29\x29\x5f\x3d\x6a\x6f\x69\x6e\x28\x70\x6f\x70\x28\x29\x29\x3b\x65\x76\x61\x6c\x28\x5f\x29"
```

This string is the one `eval`ed in the last line. But surprise, the contents of that string are just

```
_='[~[(pmqwt{n{|}|{t}yp|}mqw|{]]((uqnr|}yvzw]+qss{s{{s{{{mzw])()~][(u[}y[x]}[o])qwn|}r]]}+o|y!uq+!}z[!}{y]+(x!ow+[}]vx+[~)ux})tyo[o]})[s]+zr|!}{{|{q[{p[~})z{o[]nyuzmy!v';for(i of'mnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~')with(_.split(i))_=join(pop());eval(_)
```

---

So what does - still obfuscated - code do?

```
var _='[~[(pmqwt{n{|}|{t}yp|}mqw|{]]((uqnr|}yvzw]+qss{s{{s{{{mzw])()~][(u[}y[x]}[o])qwn|}r]]}+o|y!uq+!}z[!}{y]+(x!ow+[}]vx+[~)ux})tyo[o]})[s]+zr|!}{{|{q[{p[~})z{o[]nyuzmy!v';
for (var i of 'mnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~')
  with (_.split(i))
    _=join(pop());
eval(_)
```

Removing the `with` magic, we get

```
for (var i of 'mnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~') {
  let temp = _.split(i);
  _ = temp.join(temp.pop());
}
```

So for all of these characters from `m` to `z`, it splits `_` by that, takes the last part out, and joins it back together, effectively

- replacing `m` by `y!v`,
- replacing `n` by `yuz`,
- replacing `o` by `[]`,
- replacing `p` by `[~})z{`,
- replacing `q` by `[{`,
- replacing `r` by `|!}{{|{`,
- replacing `s` by `]+z`,
- replacing `t` by `y[][[]]})[`,
- replacing `u` by `x})`,
- replacing `v` by `x+[~)`,
- replacing `w` by `+[}]`,
- replacing `x` by `![]`,
- replacing `y` by `]+(`,
- replacing `z` by `[!}{`,
- replacing `{` by `+!}`,
- replacing `|` by `]+(!![]})[`,
- replacing `}` by `+[]`,
- replacing `~` by `][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]`

and after all that we get for `_` to be `eval`ed the code

```
[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]])()
```

Now doesn't that [look](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4170978/1048572) [familiar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7202157/1048572)? It's good old [jsfuck](http://www.jsfuck.com/)!

> I found this code as a part of some game engine code

I doubt it. Looks much more like a submission to a code obfusciation context. However, it doesn't appear to be hand-crafted, more likely someone just blindly chained multiple obfusciation tools together.